# The expression « Si j'en suis là aujourd'hui »

Tags: expressions

> **Si j'en suis là aujourd'hui**, c'est en grande partie grâce à ce site et à ses nombreux utilisateurs.

Here, I’m talking specifically about « en l'apprentissage du français » only, and about nothing else. I wonder if the sentence as is might not be misconstrued as if I owe everything in my life to this site?

What is an idiomatic way to add a restrictive meaning to this expression?

> Si j'en suis là aujourd'hui (**quant à l'apprentissage du français**), c'est en grande partie grâce à ce site et à ses nombreux utilisateurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ta première phrase est correcte et ne veut pas dire que tu dois tout à ce site mais c'est vrai qu'il y a besoin de préciser pour quelqu'un qui arriverait et ne connaîtrait rien du contexte. Donc la question est de comment spécifier ce contexte.

« En » comme tu le proposes d'abord ne convient pas, du moins on ne peut pas l'utiliser seul. Tu pourrais employer l'expression « en ce qui concerne ». « Quant à  » par contre convient très bien. Il y a d'autres tournures qui conviendraient aussi :
 - concernant
 - au sujet de
 - relativement à
 - à propos de

Mais tout ça bien que correct me semble un peu lourd et à mon avis il serait préférable de tourner la phrase autrement. Par exemple en employant un verbe qui permette d'introduire le niveau de français directement :

> Si j'ai progressé si rapidement en français c'est en grande partie grâce à ce site et à ses nombreux utilisateurs.
>
> Si j'ai atteint un bon niveau en français c'est en grande partie grâce à ...

Comment: Hi. How does this one sound: "Si mon niveau de maîtrise du français en est là aujourd'hui"? On a side note: Regarding the phrasing "mon niveau de maîtrise", does it mean "my current level", or does it sound as if I have already mastered this language? Merci.

Comment: "Si mon niveau de maîtrise du français en est là aujourd'hui" sounds OK. It reflects your current level since you add *en est là aujourd'hui*. The word "maitrise " here does not necessarily mean it is good, you can say of SO qu'il a une mauvaise maitrise de quelque chose but personally I prefer using the verb je maitrise bien / si bien/ mal/ etc.

Comment: Merci. Besides the already mentioned six phrases, can "pour ce qui est de" work as well? "Si j'en suis là aujourd'hui (pour ce qui est de l'apprentissage du français)"

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Je trouve que "mon niveau de maîtrise" est un peu pompeux, lourd, voir prétentieux. Je sens une forte connotation positive avec cette tournure, comme si tu voulais qu'on soit jaloux. Si j'entendais un natif français utiliser ce genre de phrase, je penserais qu'il veut utiliser des mots compliqué pour montrer qu'il en connait. Car en fait "Si mon niveau de français en est là aujourd'hui..." (sans utiliser "maîtrise") est tout a fait correct, donc ajouter "maîtrise" semble inutile...

Comment: *Pour ce qui est de* pourrait se dire  mais c'est lourd ici, je ne le dirais pas puisqu'on peut dire autrement.